# Youtube videos link result on website search engine

Tags: mysql, youtube, search-engine

I am working on a mySQL search engine for a website and One of the fields of the db is youtube links.

Now When information for that row is displayed the youtube link needs to be displayed as a video, not as a link.

How can I achieve this?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways of doing it but the way presented to you when you check the embed code on YouTube itself is -

```
<iframe width="420" height="315" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/{vid_id}" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```